# Script Debugger is not allowed to send keystrokes

Tags: applescript, accessibility, keystroke

I get in Script Debugger the following error message:

System Events got an error: Script Debugger is not allowed to send keystrokes.

Although I did tick the box "System Events" below "Script Debugger" in the "Automation" item of the "Privacy" menu in  "Security and Privacy settings"

I unticked the box, restarted my laptop,  ticked again the box, restarted my laptop again. My version of "Script Debugger" is 7.0.5 it's a trial license

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    key code 53
end tell

both report the same error message

Comment: Did you add Script Debugger also in the Accessibility section?

Answer (score 2):

Add accessibility permission to `Script Editor` under:

**System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility**

[image]